# connection string issue with mysql and eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse

I am new to android development. I need to connect to database:

```
urlConexionMySQL = 
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/[DBName]:[port]?user=name&password=pwd";
```

But its not working.
I get error:

```
unable to resolve static method 7867:  
Ljava/lang/management/managementfactory;.getThreadMXBean()
Ljava/lang/management/ThreadMXBean;
```

How can I fix this error?

> 03-08 09:37:02.872: W/dalvikvm(1707): VFY: unable to resolve
>   new-instance 536 (Ljavax/naming/StringRefAddr;) in
>   Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty; 03-08
>   09:37:02.872: D/dalvikvm(1707): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006
>   03-08 09:37:02.882: D/dalvikvm(1707): DexOpt: unable to opt direct
>   call 0x2138 at 0x14 in
>   Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty;.storeTo
>   03-08 09:37:03.562: I/dalvikvm(1707): Could not find method
>   java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean, referenced
>   from method com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.appendDeadlockStatusInformation
>   03-08 09:37:03.562: W/dalvikvm(1707): VFY: unable to resolve static
>   method 7867: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getThreadMXBean
>   ()Ljava/lang/management/ThreadMXBean; 03-08 09:37:03.572:
>   D/dalvikvm(1707): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0079 03-08
>   09:37:04.012: I/System.out(1707):
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyFavAppDB?user=root&password=nonsenseNOOOOOOOOO
>   03-08 09:37:04.012: I/System.out(1707): SQLException: Could not create
>   connection to database server. 03-08 09:37:04.092:
>   I/Choreographer(1707): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread. 03-08 09:37:04.232:
>   I/Choreographer(1707): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread. 03-08 09:41:55.842:
>   I/Choreographer(1707): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Wait: you installed MySQL on your phone!?

Comment: no.. its not over phone, its on ubuntu 12.04. Please suggest.

Comment: You're executing a program on your phone, which tries to connect to a MySQL on localhost. localhost is thus your phone.